# Initializer list of variables

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

Is it possible to create an `initializer_list` of variables, like function arguments for example (cf. function `test`)?

The code below works, and neither Clang nor GCC complain about anything, but I would just like to make sure this is OK.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

template <class T>
struct array
{
    T *ptr;
    size_t len;

    array() { clear(); }
    array( T *p, size_t l ) { assign(p,l); }

    inline void clear() { ptr=nullptr; len=0; }
    inline void assign( T *p, size_t l ) { ptr=p; len=l; }

    inline T& operator[] ( size_t i ) const { return ptr[i]; }
};

template <class T>
inline array<const T> wrap( const std::initializer_list<T>& lst )
    { return array<const T>( lst.begin(), lst.size() ); }

void test( int a, int b, int c )
{
    auto ar = wrap({a,b,c});
    std::cout<< ar[2] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto a = wrap({1,2,3});
    std::cout<< a[2] << std::endl;

    test(1,2,3);
}
```

Side question; if I tried to return my wrapped array in `test`, the initializer list `{a,b,c}` would get out of scope, and the array I'm returning would be invalid -- is that correct?

Comment: I do think it is useless to use `inline` keyword in template definition. I think I also remember from "C++ Coding Standards" by Sutter and Alexandrescu that it's often useless to declare ones function inline, since its only an indication for the compiler, and more tha often the compiler is smarter than you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 auto ar = wrap({a,b,c});
```

This create a temporary array of type `int[3]`, then binds an `initializer_list<int>` to that array, then calls `wrap` which creates an `array<const int>` that refers to the array.

At the end of the expression the array is destroyed, leaving the `array<const int>` with a dangling pointer, so this is undefined behaviour:

```
 std::cout<< ar[2] << std::endl;
```

This also applies to the code in `main`, the variable `a` contains a dangling pointer and `a[2]` is undefined behaviour.

You can verify this by replacing the array of `int` with an array of types that allocate memory, so that valgrind or asan will notice the bug:

```
using V = std::vector<int>;
auto a = wrap({V{1}, V{2}, V{3}});
std::cout<< a[2].front() << std::endl;
```

Now `a[2]` is a `std::vector<int>` object, but trying to access its `front()` member causes the program to abort:

```
==28356==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x60200000efb0 at pc 0x000000401205 bp 0x7fffa46f2900 sp 0x7fffa46f28f8
READ of size 4 at 0x60200000efb0 thread T0
    #0 0x401204 in main /tmp/il.cc:28
    #1 0x3236e21d64 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x3236e21d64)
    #2 0x400ec8  (/tmp/a.out+0x400ec8)
...
```

Or with valgrind:

```
==28364== Invalid read of size 4
==28364==    at 0x400C72: main (il.cc:28)
==28364==  Address 0x51dfd20 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 4 free'd
==28364==    at 0x4A07991: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:502)
==28364==    by 0x4013BF: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:110)
==28364==    by 0x4012F8: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::deallocate(std::allocator<int>&, int*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:386)
==28364==    by 0x4011B1: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_deallocate(int*, unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:178)
==28364==    by 0x40102A: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::~_Vector_base() (stl_vector.h:160)
==28364==    by 0x400EC4: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector() (stl_vector.h:425)
==28364==    by 0x400C2A: main (il.cc:27)
```

> Side question; if I tried to return my wrapped array in test, the initializer list `{a,b,c}` would get out of scope, and the array I'm returning would be invalid -- is that correct?

It's already out of scope and `ar` already invalid even before you return it.

Comment: The key point here is that the lifetime of the temporary array used by an `initializer_list` is bound to that object only; and it is *not* extended to any other initializer_list or other object which is copied/moved/etc. from the list.

Comment: another note: using `std::array<T, N>`, or `std::vector<T>` would be hunky dory here; the problem arises because OP's `array<T>` holds a non-owning raw pointer to whatever it was initialized with; whereas those standard containers will own their own storage which is copied/moved by value from the initializers.

Comment: To clarify "at the end of the expression the array is destroyed"; this is only true because my `initializer_list` is itself a temporary, isn't it? Passing an initializer list by value, wrapping it and using the wrapped value whilst in the scope of a function would work, right?

Comment: Just to confirm what I just said, changing the argument of `wrap` to a const ref, and running `std::cout<< wrap({V{1}, V{2}, V{3}}) [2].front() << std::endl;` works, although this is definitely not a practical syntax.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn, no, it's not "only true" because of anything. All temporaries are destroyed at the end of the full expression (unless bound directly to a const reference that lives longer). The temporary array _and_ the `initializer_list` both go out of scope at the end of  the expression. The comment above this one works because you use it before the end of the full expression, before anything goes out of scope.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks, I don't see any disagreement with what I said in my first comment, so I'm having troubles understanding your first "no". With different words; the problem is that I'm trying to set a pointer which I intend to keep alive longer than its target's lifetime. If instead I passed the `initializer_list` by value to some function, causing a local copy, then I would be able to wrap it persistently within the scope of that function.

Comment: The "no" was responding to _"this is only true because my ..."_. The array goes out of scope because it's a temporary. Period. The fact the `initializer_list` is also a temporary doesn't affect the array's lifetime. The temporary array created in `func({1,2,3})` always persists for the duration of the function, "causing a local copy" doesn't change that in any way.

Comment: Hm. This distinction you make between the underlying "storage" array and the `initializer_list` itself is troubling. If the storage is released before the end of the `initializer_list`'s lifetime, then why does [this](http://cpp.sh/9bdo) work?

Comment: That's a completely different situation, there the array's lifetime _does_ get extended. You didn't say anything about using an automatic `initializer_list`, you kept talking about passing it by value, so I thought you were still only talking about uses of the form `f({...})`, where the array's lifetime is not extended by anything. There most definitely _is_ a distinction between the underlying storage array and an `initializer_list` that refers to it, and trying to do funky things with `initializer_list` objects is risky because of that distinction.